# cp, trailing slash, and copying to the same vs. to another directory

Tags: command-line, zsh

To copy a directory to another directory, the first directory should be written without the trailing slash:

```
# example 1
# this command will copy dir1 to dir2
# (dir2 is preexisting)
cp -Rip dir1 dir2/
```

Otherwise, the command will copy directory contents and not the directory itself:

```
# example 2
# this command will copy dir1 contents to dir2
# (dir2 is preexisting)
cp -Rip dir1/ dir2/
```

I do understand the difference between `dir1` and `dir1/` here, and the difference between how these two commands behave doesn't confuse me.

But to copy the directory not to another directory but to the same directory where it is currently located, the trailing slash won't make any difference. Why?

```
# example 3
# any of these commands will make a dir1 copy
# (dir1-copy isn't preexisting)
cp -Rip dir1 dir1-copy/
cp -Rip dir1/ dir1-copy/
```

And another, closely related question. Why there is no difference between how `mv dir1/ dir2/` and `mv dir1 dir2/` work? In other words, why, in respect of trailing slash in the end of the source directory, `mv` follows the logic of the third `cp` example, and not the logic of examples one and two?

Comment: @DavidAnderson Hi, David. Thanks. But then I have another, closely related question. Why there is no difference between how `mv dir1/ dir2/` and `mv dir1 dir2/` work? In other words, why, in respect of trailing slash in the end of the source directory, `mv` follows the logic of the third example, and not the logic of examples one and two?

Comment: I replaced my comment with an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is from `man cp`.

---

**NAME**
     **cp** – copy files

**SYNOPSIS**
     **cp** [**-R** [**-H** | **-L** | **-P**]] [**-fi** | **-n**] [**-alpsvXx**] `source_file` `target_file`
     **cp** [**-R** [**-H** | **-L** | **-P**]] [**-fi** | **-n**] [**-alpsvXx**]
         `source_file` `...` `target_directory`

**DESCRIPTION**
     In the first synopsis form, the **cp** utility copies the contents of the
     `source_file` to the `target_file`.  In the second synopsis form, the contents
     of each named `source_file` is copied to the destination `target_directory`.
     The names of the files themselves are not changed.  If **cp** detects an
     attempt to copy a file to itself, the copy will fail.

---

The OP's question pertains to which of the two forms given above is being used. This depends on whether the target directory exists. **The second form requires the target directory to exist.** When entering the following commands from the OP's question, the second form is used.

```
cp -Rip dir1 dir2/
cp -Rip dir1/ dir2/
```

When entering the following commands from the OP's question, the first form is used.

```
cp -Rip dir1 dir1-copy/
cp -Rip dir1/ dir1-copy/
```

With both the previous two commands, the results are the same. Directory `dir1` is duplicated, where `dir1-copy` is the name of the duplicate. The use of the `/` after `dir1` is redundant.

One can prove the first form is being used by adding an existing file to either command. For example, say there exists a file named `hi.txt` and that the following command is entered. Since there are now two source files, the second form must be used.

```
cp -Rip dir1 hi.txt dir1-copy/
```

The result will be the following error message.

```
cp: dir1-copy is not a directory
```

Since neither of the commands below produce an error message, the first form must have been used.

```
cp -Rip dir1 dir1-copy/
cp -Rip dir1/ dir1-copy/
```

### As for the OP's *"closely related question"*

The `man cp` output makes the following distinction involving the use of the `/` character after a directory name when the `-R` option is specified.

---

**-R**    If `source_file` designates a directory, **cp** copies the directory and
    
     the entire subtree connected at that point.  If the `source_file` ends
    
     in a `/`, the contents of the directory are copied rather than the
    
     directory itself....

---

No such distinctions are made in the output from `man mv`.  With the `mv` command, the trailing `/` has no special meaning.